# Run Liquibase changesets by context name

Tags: java, liquibase

*Is there any way to run only group of changesets with Liquibase API?*

The following code initialize the whole schema before starting integration test class:

```
liquibase = new Liquibase(
    LIQUIBASE_CHANGELOG_PATH,
    new FileSystemResourceAccessor(),
    new JdbcConnection(embeddedTestDatabase.getConnection())
);
liquibase.dropAll();
liquibase.update(""); // PROBLEM: for some reason this launch all changesets including changesets with name `test`
```

Now I want to do something like DBUnit's `@DatabaseSetup` before specific test method - means execute only changesets with `test` context:

```
liquibase.update("test"); // PROBLEM : this also run all changesets

<changeSet author="me" id="some_id" logicalFilePath="some_path" context="test">
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID, CREATED_AT, CREATED_BY, NAME) VALUES (1, '2017-09-15 16:55:57.558', 'My company');
    </sql>
    <rollback>
        DELETE FROM COMPANY;
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Does it run *all* other changesets, and these *other* changesets - do they have its own `context`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [the "contexts" feature in Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) does what you need here.

The example given in the docs matches your requirements.

The docs explain:

> When you run the migrator though any of the available methods, you can pass in a set of contexts to run. Only changeSets marked with the passed contexts will be run.
>
> If you don’t assign a context to a changeSet, it will run all the time, regardless of what contexts you pass in to the migrator.

So I think you need to add a context other than "test" to the rest of your migrations, if you don't want them run here. Maybe "`main`"?

Comment: yes, all my old changesets don't have context. How about setting `context="main"` to old changesets if we're already supporting clients. Will context="main" change checksums?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Adding a context should not change its checksum, see http://www.liquibase.org/2009/03/what-effects-changeset-checksums.html

Comment: tahnk you a lot!